# How can I run my code with Visual Studio when I have an error with my database?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework

When I try to run my code, I get this error with Visual Studio:

> MySql.Data.Entity.EF6' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.'

I don't understand what the problem is
The error occurred when I try to load:

```
 public triptiekEntities()
            : base("name=triptiekEntities")
        {
        }
```

my config file is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="traceLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="PConfig.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="triptiekEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Triptiek.csdl|res://*/Data.Triptiek.ssdl|res://*/Data.Triptiek.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=fotothek;database=triptiek;password=fotothek&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Please help me.

Comment: And you really have installed the correct MySQL .net driver?

Comment: yes . but is it possible that visual studio don't take the good one ?

Comment: That would appear to be what the error message is saying, yes

Comment: Remove the line `<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"...`.

Comment: Try to modify the "defaultConnectionFactory" to `<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />`.